# "Program Compatibility Assistant" pop-up shown

Tags: c#, .net

An .exe is build in "anyCPU" configuration. While running in 64-bit machine, "Program Compatibility Assistant" pop-up is shown (in Standard User). The same .exe executes fine in 32-bit machine without any problem.

Building the .exe in "x64" mode, it worked fine in 64-bit machine.

What might be the problem, because of which the "Program Compatibility Assistant" pop-up is shown?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. It was not due to 32-bit or 64-bit. It was running an .exe which was not vista aware type or required higher privileges to execute. So, while building an exe a manifest file was added and in the manifest requiredexecutionlevel was updated to be "higherprivileges" and added supported OS guids to Windows 7. Similarly supported OS can be added for Windows 8 also. Hence building the exe with the manifest resolved the issue.